# Convert Sentinel 5p to GeoTIFF

Tags: r, r-raster, terra, ncdf4

How I can convert Sentinel 5p (PRODUCT/methane_mixing_ratio_bias_corrected) to GeoTIFF in R?

I want to convert two Sentinel 5p (PRODUCT/methane_mixing_ratio_bias_corrected) to GeoTIFF in R simultaneously, the data is in the Google Drive link;
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e76nLQwaNAv7McrUpl7Yq8wyxf_EiHmp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For questions asking for code help please provide a small sample of your data in the question, not in a link to an outside source. You can provide a small sample with `dput(yourdata)`. Edit your question to copy and paste the result.

Comment: I am getting one raster from one file, how I can get for more than one files. 
ncpath <- "~/Jason/"

ncname <- "S5P_RPRO_L2__CH4____20210419T181023_20210419T195154_18222_03_020400_20221122T181703.SUB"

ncfname <- paste(ncpath,ncname, ".nc4", sep="")

nc <- nc_open(ncfname)

ncatt_get(nc, "PRODUCT/methane_mixing_ratio_bias_corrected")

raster_layer <- raster::raster(no2tc, xmn = min(lon), xmx = max(lon), ymn = min(lat), ymx = max(lat))

terra::writeRaster(raster_layer, "sentinel2.tif", filetype = "GTiff", overwrite = TRUE)